# Google Books API returning 404 on Bookshelf GET

Tags: javascript, google-books-api

I run a website for my book club that uses Google Books to pull cover images. To do this, I add the books to the Have Read bookshelf on my Google Books library and then I use this GET in JavaScript.

```
`
url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/myID/bookshelves/4/volumes?key=' + APIKey + '&maxResults=40']; 
xmlgoogle.open("GET", url[0]);`
```

This has worked completely fine for years, but in the last week, I'm getting a 404 when I try to retrieve the bookshelf data. Has something changed about the Google Books API that makes this GET no longer work?

Normally, I get a list of book data. Now I get a 404 from the exact same command with the exact same library.

Comment: what happens if you open the URL directly in your browser or use `curl` or equivalent